# Application launch by double click issue

Tags: c#, windows, exe.config

I am encountering a perplexing issue with an application, let's call it (for company privacy purposes) "MYAPPLICATION" where the executable is named "MYAPPLICATION.exe."
This application, developed using various programming languages including C#, makes use of a ".exe.config" file to select the correct versions of certain DLLs.

We are considering eliminating this configuration file once we have a better dependency management system in place.

The application undergoes an installation process on end-user machines.

Approximately 25% of these installations run smoothly without any issues. However, for the remaining 75%, we encounter a peculiar behavior discrepancy based on how the application is launched.

Specifically, on other machines, the following occurs:

- If the application is manually launched and then a file is opened
  within it, there are no problems.
- However, if the file to be opened is double-clicked, the application crashes.

Upon investigating the crash, we discovered the root of the problem. When the application is launched via a double-click on the file, the Task Manager displays something like "MYAP~3272.exe" instead of "MYAPPLICATION.exe."

This value remains consistent across different machines experiencing this issue. Interestingly, appending "MYAP~3272.exe.config" resolves the issue, indicating that the match with this new file (obtained by duplicating the original ".exe.config" file) allows the application to function properly.

The crash is due to the fact that if no matching .exe.config is found, a wrong versioned .dll is loaded and there is a memory mismatch.

Unfortunately, I am unable to provide further details until Monday when I have access to the company laptop. For example, I can verify whether the application path is correct or corrupted.

In any case, does anyone know why such an issue might occur on Windows systems?

Thank you.

Comment: The name *MYAP~3272* is a short name which used to be created on older systems before long filenames were introduced. You should check the settings on the offending systems to find out why they are not fully supporting long names. It also could be that the system has one of the old style FAT16 file systems.

Comment: _"We are considering eliminating this configuration file once we have a better dependency management system in place."_ - `App.config` files exist because that's just how .NET Framework 1.x-4.x lets you set-up binding-redirects (and everything else) - you can't really choose to "eliminate" them because it's just a fact-of-life in the .NET Framework world.

Comment: _"In any case, does anyone know why such an issue might occur on Windows systems?"_ 
- If I understand you correctly, you're saying that the Windows Shell file-extension / file-handler registration for your program (which would be set-up by your Installer program?) is consistently broken for most, but not all, of your user - based on that, I'd say your installer program is at fault somehow - are you using a "real" installer framework like MSI (including WIX) - or is this a ClickOnce scenario?